# give link to both image and text in rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hello I've a small bit of code how could I give link to both the icon and text ,from class i'm calling an icon

here is my code

```
       <td class="cv-class_<%= index + 1 %>">
          <a  onClick="add_new_entry('<%= personnel_cv_data_type %>')">Add <%= @content_data['lable_add_'+personnel_cv_data_type] %></a>
        </td>
```

This is the generated code

```
       <td class="cv-class_1">
          <a onclick="add_new_entry('skills')">Add Skill</a>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use this

```
 <a class="cv-class_<%= index + 1 %>" onClick="add_new_entry('<%= personnel_cv_data_type %>')">Add <%= @content_data['lable_add_'+personnel_cv_data_type] %></a>
```